# Collapse all groups at once with Tabulator component

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'd like to collapse all [groups in the tabulator component](https://tabulator.info/examples/5.5#grouping). Alas there seems no default functions to do that so I tried to implement my own solution.

```
  const groupContextMenu = [
    {
      label: 'Open all', // TODO not working
      action(ev, cell) {
        cell.getTable().getGroups().forEach(g => g.show());
      }
    },
    {
      label: 'Collapse all', // TODO not working
      action(ev, cell) {
        cell.getTable().getGroups().forEach(g => g.hide());
      }
    }
  ];
```

It doesn't work. First of all only the first group is affected and it seems to work very slow. Somehow this could be related to technical limitations? It seems groupings are only rendered when scrolling down and they become visible in the viewport.